# C# Find folders from a path and output it in a comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, path, find, directory

Does anyone know how to find folders from a path (for example; C:/testfolder) and output all the folders in a comboBox that begins with a ".". So if a folder in the path is called ".test", it'll show up in the comboBox. However, if it does not begin with a ".", it will not show up.

I don't have very much code at the moment but here's what i've got:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboBox.Items.Add("Test");
        ComboBox.Items.Add("Test2");
    }

    private void CMDSwitch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I would also like to know how to browse for files and/or folders, select them and add them to a combo box.

Edit: Thanks alot guys, I got it working by using

```
string path = @"D:\TestFolder";

foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path, ".*"))
{
    ComboBox.Items.Add(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm
System.IO namespace has three lovely classes in it.
Files, Directories and Path.

Stuff like Directories.GetFiles for instance.

As for browsing to a file or Folder. Built in controls in the Toolbox OpenFileDialog and OpenFolderDialog might come in handy.

Get yourself a c# and .net book and have a read, but a good general rule, is if you think it should already be there , it almost certainly is.

Comment: Well, i only have a book about XNA at the moment.

Comment: I'd been programming for years, well decades, and I couldn't find stuff I knew was in there. The .net framework is huge.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Directory.GetDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx) to get a list of directories matching your specific pattern.

```cs
Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `DirectoryInfo` and `Directory` classes, i.e to get an array of `FileInfo`:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\testfolder").GetFiles();
```

To get a subset of directories you can use Linq to e.g. only grab those whose folder names start with `"."`:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\testfolder");
var dirs = di.EnumerateDirectories()
             .Where(d => d.Name.StartsWith("."));
```

Comment: ...or even better GetDirectories()

Comment: One thing i should have mentioned is that i am almost completely new to programming :/

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = YOUR_PATH;
foreach (string dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    if (new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name.StartsWith("."))
    {
        ComboBox.Items.Add(dir);
    }
}
```

Note it isn't recursive, as you didn't asked it.

Comment: Thanks alot! I got it working but dir.StartsWith didn't work so i used Directory.GetDirectories(path, ".*")

Comment: @Metamist Oops. Previous code checks that the full path was started with '.', not the directory name. See edited answer.